# Virtual environment created in conda with python3 gets python 2.7

Tags: python-3.x, anaconda, conda

I'm using MacOS and anaconda version 1.7.2. I created a conda virtual environment with version 3.7 but got version 2.7.

I created it using this command:
`conda create --name test python=3.7 pip`
Once I activate it and check the python version with `python --version` it says 2.7 instead of 3.7.

How can I solve it?
Thanks

Comment: does it appear next to the command line input you are in?

Comment: if you mean the virtual env name then yes, it does

Comment: Check "which python".